# Adding png meme/icon to existing true type or open type font

Tags: fonts, emoji, truetype, opentype, ttx-fonttools

I want to add a png icon to an existing font for use in my terminal on macOS. I've looked into using the python fonttools package, but I can't figure out how you would add a png to the font. It sounds like I need to modify/add the sbix table, but I'm struggling to find an example where this happens. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ttx (alias from fonttools) for extract and pack your font.

```
ttx -z extfile YourFont
```

Doc: https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttx.html